# Email list/group without the need to make an account

Tags: gratis, email, mailing-list

I'm looking for a simple email list/group (online service) that I can just add people's email addresses too, and then those people can mail to one list email address to reach all.

This is what Google groups does, but there are two things I don't like there:

- Google wants you to have an account. Some people may not have one.
- Other people have a Gmail account with email address X but want to use email address Y. Yes, Google can handle access through multiple email addresses, but I always have people who don't now how to do that, get confused, and then it's a lot of work for me trying to get that right/explained.

It should be 'set up and go', without the account 'hassle'.

Metrics/other requirements:

- Size of mailing list: 20-25 people
- Total mail volume: 500/month max
- Free
- Email addresses should be invisible for each other
- "Reply to all" behaviour is good enough
- No ads